# What is Blood Offering?

Tags: the-secret-world

The damage skill point track for Blood Magic, Empowered Blood, says, "While Blood Offering is active, your Blood abilities deal *X*% more damage."

What is Blood Offering? I don't see any ability with that name in the Blood ability tree.

Comment: [How does Blood Offering get activated?](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=40980) says that blood offering is a dot (damage over time) that gets activated when you use a blood ability without enough resources for it

Comment: @axrwkr Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Empowered Blood]

This is discussed on the secret world forums.

[How does Blood Offering get activated?](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=40980)

> blood offering is a dot (damage over time) that gets activated when you use a blood ability without enough resources for it.

This is also mentioned in the following thread about blood dps rotations

[Blood DPS](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=72639)

> Bloodshot (no resources, puts up Blood Offering...)